# Replace nth occurence in a string between two characters

Tags: regex

i have to use regular expressions to cross out some content in a string.

For example
`SomeText;content1|content2|content3|||content6||content8`

As you can see, the contents are separated by pipes. Contents do not have a fixed length and can consist of any characters.
Now I want to replace `content6` by `xxxxxx`. Therefore I need something like *"replace the content between the pipes on occurence number 6"*

Result should be:
`SomeText;content1|content2|content3|||xxxxxx||content8`

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you determining that content6 is the 6th occurrence? What determines, and delineates, each *occurrence*? Are you completely ignoring any content before the first semicolon?

Comment: Then have your pattern match something-or-nothing-followed-by-a-pipe five times before that ...

Comment: Depending on the language/environment, you could also just split the text on the pipes, and reconstruct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there won't be any "escaped pipes" we need to deal with, you could search for

```
^((?:[^|]*\|){5})[^|]*(.*)$
```

and replace that with `\1xxxxxx\2`.

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KqO24p/1).

**Explanation:**

`[^|]*` matches any number of characters besides `|`, so `(?:[^|]*\|){5}` matches everything up to and including the 5th pipe.

Comment: Thank you very much. This one worked perfectly. Tried a long time and did not get it working.